# AS3 How can I create a loop that declares vars?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, loops, var

I declare these three vars as MovieClips:

```
var bg_mc_1:MovieClip;
var bg_mc_2:MovieClip;
var bg_mc_3:MovieClip;
```

Then I put them in an array:

```
var bg_mc:Array = [bg_mc_1, bg_mc_2, bg_mc_3];
```

Then I do this loop to add the MovieClips into a MC that is already on the stage:

```
for(i=0; i<=2; i++){
    bg_mc[i] = new bg_class_1() as MovieClip;
    bg_holder.addChild(bg_mc[i]);
}
```

Is there anyway to make the first step dynamic? For instance something like:

```
for(i=0; i<=2; i++){
    var this["bg_mc_"+i]:MovieClip;
    bg_mc.push(this["bg_mc_"+i])
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create MovieClips dynamically :

```
for(var i=0; i<=2; i++){
    this["bg_mc_"+i] = new MovieClip();
    bg_mc.push(this["bg_mc_"+i]);
}
```

Altho if you don't need a reference to the MovieClip outside of the `bg_mc` array you can always do

```
for(var i=0; i<=2; i++){
    bg_mc.push(new MovieClip());
}
```